# Dell Boomi - Parse values from email body

Tags: integration, netsuite, email-parsing, boomi

I'm working with the Dell Boomi platform and NetSuite.

I have a unique situation where we need to retrieve emails from an inbox with a mail(IMAP) connector then take the body of the email and read it line by line to extract specific information.

[image: Crude diagram of what I need]
This is a crude diagram of what I need to do.

---

The mail(IMAP) connector works perfectly, but I can't figure out what to do from there. I'm trying to learn Boomi and it's proving more of a challenge.

Basically I need to create 3 variables from the body of the email:

```
var customer = [];
var memo = [];
var amount = [];
```

The email body being parsed would look something like this with no headers:

> -----Original Message-----
>
> From: info@somesite.com
>
> Sent: Wednesday, August 28, 2019 9:07 PM
>
> To: reports@somesite.com;
>
> Subject: Event Log: Report Recap Subject Line
>
> Example 123456, 123412532452346346: ALKNBAQWIOET235QA08WSAQ2038YTQ12{
>
> Example 120985, 109285710928561239: IO2Q0AIHJG698AE64A98GA654AG98DGF{
>
> Example 489072, 987651498795654987: S54DGFH9A84D65F4A6SDF98A4SD138A4{
>
> 12341253643876843589, #12345, 100.00
>
> 12387019287654984616, #12324, 125.00
>
> 12359870923654987465, #51232, 100.00

This portion of the email is what I need to read from and ignore the rest

> 12341253643876843589, #12345, 100.00
>
> 12387019287654984616, #12324, 125.00
>
> 12359870923654987465, #51232, 100.00

I assume I would need a Data Process shape to manipulate the information. But I don't understand what scripting should be included to pull these into variables that can be connected to a map in a future step.

Crudely written, I need the script to do the following:

- Read line one of the email, and check if the firstword is at least 20 characters long
- If it's not read the next line
- If it is store it in the `customer` variable, store the value after the , into the `memo` variable (#12345) then store the last , value as the `amount` variable
- then allow those variables to be passed/mapped into NetSuite

I'm sorry if this doesn't make much sense. I'm really hopeful that I can find help here though. I'm trying my best to learn this but it's just over my head, desperate, and I just need help...

My current process in Boomi, I have no clue what to do after this, again the email is pulling perfectly.
[image: current boomi process]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it would be to basically split the document by line, push it through a map and then evaluate whether the first column is greater than zero via a route.  Skip the variables and just handled it via a map. This assumes you have some fundamental understanding of DellDoomi.

Example:
[image]

Moving from left to right:

1. "Test Data" - message with your example text so I could test.
2. "Split Document - Flat File - Split By Line" - This would be where you'd start and connect this to your mail connector.  It's a Data Process Shape, Split Documents
   [image]

That will basically split your email message into individual documents per line.

3. "Flat File" - This is a map.  I manually created a new Flat File Profile(email message input), Comma Delimited with 3 Elements.  This is bringing structure to each line.  Source and target are using the same Profile, your right side would probably be the profile for netsuite, mapping the appropriate columns.

[image]

4. "Route" - This basically looks at the value in the first column and checks if it's greater than 0.  Anything else gets routed to Default and we don't do anything with those.  Routing by the first column of the "email message input" profile that had been created.

[image]

5. "The Greater than 0" branch would be where you hook up your destination.  As this should only be those 3 lines as shown in your example since those are actually greater than zero.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim! I'm marking your response as the answer since it works for the scenario I gave. 

I failed to give an accurate representation of my actual data which is completely my fault. Technically our column looks like this with alpha-numeric and text: 

4T1CE38P76U656260: NO ORDER FOUND FOR Type  (Trans Charge), Voucher 00XY9230A01, $295.00

If we push it to a flat file our first columns look like this:

COLUMN 1: 4T1CE38P76U656260: NO ORDER FOUND FOR Type  (Trans Charge)
COLUMN 2: Voucher 00XY9230A01
COLUMN 3: $295.00

Comment: Do you know of any other sources to help in learning Boomi aside from the Boomi Documentation? I'd love to be able to look at actual use cases rather than generic definitions. Thank you!!!

Comment: There's training, https://boomi.com/services/training/, which I believe is free.  If you have access to the platform there is the process library, which has pre-built processes you can review and reuse. There might be other resources I'm not aware of.

Comment: Reading you other comment, then what specific data would you need in that scenario?  The voucher and amount or would you also need that first alpha-numeric value as well?

Comment: In that scenario the data we needed to grab were 4T1CE38P76U656260, 00XY9230A01, $295.00. Thank you for your follow up, with the help of a colleague we were able to get what we needed up and running. We split the email line by line then used Groovy scripting to get and set properties that held the information we wanted from the email. After that we were able to query NetSuite and Update the targeted record. It's working very nicely now. Thanks again for your follow up and earlier advice!